# How do I remove ndiswrapper completely?

Tags: wireless, uninstall, ndiswrapper

I would like to remove the ndiswrapper from my system after mistakenly installing it to enable a wifi card that it turned out had native Ubuntu support and only required firmware.

What is the full process and what things must I be aware of?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Exactly what karthick87 asked. Depending on how you installed it will depend how to remove it. anyway i will put an answer to it just in case you did it the normal synaptic/software center way.

Comment: @karthick87 - if anyone is installing anything by compiling it, they need to be thwacked and then polity shown how to use debs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed ndiswrapper using the Software Center or Synaptic do the following to remove completely

You have 4 ways (2 of them will do it Completely):

Go to Synaptic and search fo ndiswrapper. Right click on it and select Remove Completely. then Accept.

Go to Software Center and search for ndiswrapper and click on REMOVE.

The following 2 options will remove it completely. What i mean is, it will remove what Synaptic and Software Center can remove plus all config files and even the downloaded package of ndiswrapper.

In the terminal type (Using apt-get):

```
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 ndiswrapper-modules-1.9
```

In the terminal type (Using aptitude my favorite):

```
sudo aptitude purge ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 ndiswrapper-modules-1.9
```

This applies to any other program you want to remove either from system to not use or completely removing the config files and downloaded packages.

NOTE: In the case of Synaptic if you do the Complete Removal option then you are actually removing it completely. There is also another option that says just Remove which leaves the config and packages downloaded there. Just in case you want to use it later on.