# ndiswrapper windows drivers uninstall issue

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, ndiswrapper

What can I do to uninstall this program? It was done in an attempt in vain to fix my WLAN. Now it is not serving any purpose to search for Windows drivers, even if not really needed to remove.

I installed it via this cmd
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk

Thank you

Comment: How you uninstall something depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1160595/edit) to clearly explain how you installed ndiswrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling (for the most part) is simply reversing the installation method. For example, if to install it you used:

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
```

Then to uninstall it you would use:

```
sudo apt-get remove ndisgtk
```

There are additional details you might want to read:

- [How do I cleanly remove NDISwrapper?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96557/how-do-i-cleanly-remove-ndiswrapper)
- [How do I remove ndiswrapper completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19013/how-do-i-remove-ndiswrapper-completely)
- [How to Uninstall Ndiswrapper](https://sourceforge.net/p/ndiswrapper/ndiswrapper/Uninstall_HowTo/)

The last link deals with the windows wrapped drivers that are created in `/lib/modules/uname -r/misc`, `/etc/ndiswrapper` and `/etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper`.

That said I'm often one of those "Leave well enough alone" guys and even if I wasn't using Windows Wrapped Drivers anymore I might be tempted to just leave them be. On the other hand if `dkms` was compiling the new drivers with each kernel update and the time was distracting me, I probably would purge it all.

Comment: Thanks so much, it was working out:)

Comment: @Erikajana Are you saying you went with the first command `sudo apt remove ndisgtk`? If so kindly click the grey check mark next to the answer so others know what worked for you.